# Xamarin Mac Toolbar and WindowController.h

Tags: macos, xamarin, mono, xamarin.mac

The question is:

I use this [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/working-with-toolbars/) in order to create a toolbar in my first Xamarin.Mac application. But the problem is that **WindowController.h** mentioned in the guide does not exist and simply cannot Ctrl-Drag outlet or action to **ViewController.h**

Any suggestions how to do things right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you make sure to add a custom class to your NSWindowController?  You can give it a custom class name in XCode and then when you return to Xamarin Studio there will be a C# class generated with a code behind file.

Once you have a C# class in your project with the [Register] attribute (automatically added in the code-behind when the class is generated), the XCode project will have the corresponding header file to add outlets to.